# Chartjs tooltip anchor point position on bar charts

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a bar chart using Chartjs, with a fixed y-axis max. Sometimes the data can exceed the max, but the hover tooltip is always anchored to the top of the bars so it cannot be seen. The tooltips' `position` option does not really work for me.

So, is there a way to display the tooltip at the bottom of the bars? Or can it follow the hovering mouse cursor like [canvasjs](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/basics-of-creating-html5-chart/tool-tip/)?

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("chart").getContext("2d");
var barChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                display: true,
                ticks: {
                    min: 0,
                    max: 120
                },
            }],
        },
        tooltips: {
            // position: 'nearest',
            position: 'average',
        },
        legend: {
            display: false
        }
    },
    data: {
        labels: ["A", "B", "C", "D"],
        datasets: [{
            label: "Data Set 1",
            backgroundColor: [
                '#44b2d7',
                '#44b2d7',
                '#44b2d7',
                '#44b2d7',
            ],
            borderColor: [
                '#44b2d7',
                '#44b2d7',
                '#44b2d7',
                '#44b2d7'
            ],
            borderWidth: 0,
            data: [131, 65, 165, 85]
        }]
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart" height="180"></canvas>
```

Comment: Seems there is a bug with SO's snippet like [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326126/error-while-calling-jquery-show-in-stack-overflow-snippet). Please go to full page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

New modes can be defined by adding functions to the Chart.Tooltip.positioners map.
You can create your custom postitioning like in the [Doc](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#position-modes) of chartjs:

```
    Chart.Tooltip.positioners.custom = function(elements, eventPosition) {
    /** @type {Chart.Tooltip} */
    var tooltip = this;

    /* ... */

    return {
        x: eventPosition.x,
        y: eventPosition.y
    };
}
```

you need to set your custom function into your options when rendering your chart:

```
tooltips: { 
            position : 'custom',   //<-- important same name as your function above      
            callbacks: {
              label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
               var label = Math.floor(tooltipItem.yLabel*100)/100+" "+data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label;
               return label;
              }
            }
          }
```

Look my full [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/edicarlos10/35081nag/) example.

Comment: Works like a charm! One trivial follow-up question, the tooltip follows the mouse cursor movement in your fiddle but not in my own dev environment (same chart option, same browser).  What could be the possible cause?

Comment: In yours DevTools is showing some error ? Did you clear your browser cache ? Can you give more details about your dev environment ?

Comment: @EdiCarlos, will you please share same demo in angular using ng2-charts?